# Statistical Test between two Gaussian Mixture Models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Say that I have two Gaussian Mixture Models. How would I determine whether they are statistically different from one another?

**EDIT:**

I'm thinking about doing pairwise tests for each Gaussian?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this? Do you have two data sets, each with a best-fit GMM, and you want to test whether the generating GMMs are different? Are you just given two sets of GMM parameters and you want to determine if they're "different enough" (in which case we'll need much more info)?

Comment: I have two GMM samples. I want to compare whether they are different or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "GMM samples"?

Comment: -1 and vote to close as unclear for reasons listed above.

Comment: I think this makes perfect sense. I have two GMMs and I want to determine whether they are from different populations or not

Comment: You have two samples or two models? Those are not the same.

Comment: Two samples and I fit a GMM for each of those samples; hence I have 2 GMMs.

Comment: What would you like to compare in this scenario? You have two different models fitted to two different datasets...

Comment: Whether they are statistically different!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zero inflate models vs generalized mixture model](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78973/zero-inflate-models-vs-generalized-mixture-model)

Comment: Whether *what* is statistically different? The data (what aspect of it?), the models?

Comment: Yes the models, what else?

Comment: @zero but those are two different models, computed on different data. Example: you want to compare model that assumes normal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for human height to another model that assumes binomial distribution for number of heads in $n$ coin tosses parametrized by $p$ -- what and how would you like to compare in here? It is like comparing taste of pizza to speed of a sports car...

Comment: This is just a two sample test where each of the samples is bimodal in nature.

Comment: I would say they effectively want a test of whether the two sets of samples come from the same distribution, but potentially making use of an assumption that the true distribution is some kind of Gaussian mixture. So rather than doing a non-parametric test one can perhaps do the test based on fitting a Gaussian mixture model.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Bayesian setting,

For example, assuming you have 2 Gaussians in each model, The posterior distribution on the two models is a good way to measure how well each model describe the sample.

[Bayes Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor) can be used to measure difference/similarity between the two models

Comment: Nice, but I'd like to stick to the Frequentist school.