# ZINB or ZIP for cetacean data with many zeros

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, zero-inflation

I am stuck in my thesis to conduct a GLM with cetacean data (count, density, effort and covariates). I have over 94% zeros in my dataset meaning I should be using a GLM with zero-inflated negative binomial/ or Poisson? Do I still need an offset within the equation?
In other journal papers regarding cetaceans I have never read about ZINB or ZIP. Would it not be very common?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just because there are many zeros does not necessarily mean you need a zero inflated model; a Poisson or negative binomial regression may be adequate. I would recommend you follow [the model selection approach gung proposes in the proposed duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78977/1352).

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. You are correct to question if a zero-inflated/hurdle model might relevant here. Please see my answer below for more details.

Comment: But it looks like this Q has a better answer than the proposed dup ...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed having 94% of zeros sounds like a rather large proportion of zeros so your original idea of using a zero-inflated or a hurdle model is not unfounded. Any reasonable analyst would. :)

That said, as Stephan mentioned in his comments, the large proportion of zeros does not necessitate the need for a  zero-inflated or a hurdle model. I think it is very likely that you will indeed need a ZI count model (94% seems very large without any context).
I would suggest looking at some formal references for example: Hilbe's [Modeling Count Data](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/modeling-count-data/BFEB3985905CA70523D9F98DA8E64D08), Chapt. 7 "*Problems with Zeros*", is very nice and accessible. It mentions a number of approaches (e.g. Boundary likelihood ratio tests, Vuong tests, etc.) Zuur et al. [Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R](https://highstat.com/index.php/mixed-effects-models-and-extensions-in-ecology-with-r) Chapt. 11 "*Zero-Truncated and Zero-Inflated Models for Count Data*" is also consider quite a standard reference.

Regarding the use of an offset: Using an offset is mostly relevant if it makes sense to view the response variable as part of  a rate instead of raw counts (e.g. number of infected individuals per 100K). Without knowing your exact research question one cannot answer this definitively; the interpretation of offset has been covered a couple of times in this forum, eg. see the following threads for more info:

- [When to use an offset in a Poisson regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/)
- [In a Poisson model, what is the difference between using time as a covariate or an offset?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175349)

In any case, it would be good to consider using rootgrams to visualise your results. Kleiber & Zeileis (2014) [Visualizing Count Data Regressions Using Rootograms](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2016.1173590) is a good reference for the matter (free version [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.01311.pdf)).

A final comment about the perceived lack of ZI model use in "*journal papers regarding cetaceans*": It might be the case that in the papers you have seen ZI/hurdle models were unnecessary, unable to be estimated correctly or were simply ignored; we don't know that. Do not hesitate using a "more sophisticated" model; ultimately it is a matter if such a model (hierarchical, spatial, zero-inflated, what have you) is relevant to our research question and if we can correctly estimate it.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the long and in-depth answer. I will follow your advice and get back to you if things remain unclear.

Comment: I am glad I could help. If this answer is helpful please consider upvoting it and if it resolves your question marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I realised that my GLM model is underdispersed: `M4<-glm(HP_CT~BAT+FEA+AnTPV+HU3,family=poisson(), data=irishseafront)` where the dispersion factor was =0.955. calculated by `dispersion <- M4$deviance / M4$df.residual’ .  Is this close enough to 1 in order to proceed with a Poisson, or maybe even ZIP? Or do I need to address the minor under-dispersion - if so, how? Thanks again for any ideas or comments

Comment: This is very likely OK. You can try a hurdle model as a simple solution or a generalised Poisson. There are some even more specialised models (e.g. [Conway-Maxwell-Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%E2%80%93Maxwell%E2%80%93Poisson_distribution-) but for that you describe they seem like an overkill. It is important to note that it will be good to examine as why you think under-dispersion occurs (if indeed it occurs).